# Magento - assign multiple product ids to a category

Tags: magento, collections, categories

I have a category "new" that I want to assign to, via a daily cron, the most recent 120 products.
I am trying to override the product ids assigned to a category.
Is there an easy way , like :

$category->setProductIds(array())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works like this

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryID);
$product_array = $category->getProductsPosition()
... make changes ... format : $item[$product_id] => $position_in_category
$category->setPostedProducts($product_array);
$category->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP code you can put them into the category while you are importing them.

Say you have a product called $product and a category ID called $category_id

You can set the categories which a product belongs to by doing the following

```
$categories = array($category_id);
$product->setCategoryIds($categories);
$product->save();
```

f the product already has categories and you'd like to add one more then you can use getCategoryIds() like this:

```
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
$categories[] = $categoryId;
$product->setCategoryIds($categories);
$product->save();
```

Comment: thanks ! i am aware of that version, i thought there is a way to do it from a $category object, because i also want to empty the category before assigning new products to it, and passing through all the products in the category wouldnt be that nice.

Answer (score 0):

To Remove product from category:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());
```

To Add Product to Category:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());
```

Now you can loop through all products and assign those to category using category id.

**Note:** This will not overwrite any categories the product is already in.